# Dynamically set default form values in django

Tags: django, forms, dynamic

I'm trying to find a way to dynamically set default form values. So for example, if I add a facebook login feature on my webpage, and I can get his first name and last name from what the facebook javascript returns, I want to be able to set these values as the new "value" parameter in the given form. (basically so I'm able to put the user in my database)
I was hoping that there is some sort of

```
{{ form.firstname.default = Javascript.return.firstname }}
```

that I can insert into a template but there isn't... 
Any ideas? Thank you.

Edit;; Maybe it would be better to first pass in the information into a views.py? But how would I do this? I am just considering hand writing the inputs out in the javascript field, which would be annoying...

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default value of a template variable:

```
{{ form.firstname|default:Javascript.return.firstname }}
```

assuming that {{ Javascript.return.firstname }} is valid in that template context.

Comment: wow, thats a thing? Can you show me the docs for that feature? And is "default" something that is built into the django template system?Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's build in: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#default

Comment: That doesn't work, apparently form values arent the same as regular values. I'm gunna try the jQuery way.

Answer (score 0):

The code generated by Django is all server-side, its templates can't use anything which isn't available when the page is loaded.  You need to use javascript to set the value.

For example, if your form looks like this:

```
<form id="login">
 <input name="firstname" />
</form>
```

You could use this javascript (assuming you're using jQuery):

```
// Do the facebook login, set the var fname to the first name, then:
$('#login [name=firstname]').val(fname);
```

Comment: I don't really know jquery/javascript very well to tell you the truth. So where would that line go? Can you point me to a sample function?

Comment: Inside the function which is called by the facebook code when a login is successful.