# How can you dynamically set initial value of form select field at the time of rendering django template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a requirement to render select field multiple times and each field will have pre-selected value.

Now My question is:
How can you dynamically set  initial value of django form selectfield at the time of rendering django template??

my form:

```
class RequestProdApvr(forms.Form):
    product = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Product.objects.all().order_by('code'), label='', required=False)
```

I have to use this form in multiple row in my listview and pre-populate value based on saved data.

I searched SO for the solution and non of them met my requirement...

[Django. Initial value of Choice Field dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32643473/django-initial-value-of-choice-field-dynamically)

[Dynamically set default form values in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185035/dynamically-set-default-form-values-in-django)

Hence I am posting separate question here...

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through select options and check if the current object is equals to backend options so you can mark it as selected:

```
<select name="field_name" class="form-control" id="id_field_name">
    {% for id_obj, obj in form.field_name.field.choices %}
    {% if obj == context_obj.property%}
    <option value="{{id_obj}}" selected="">{{obj}}</option>
    {% else %}
    <option value="{{id_obj}}">{{obj}}</option>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

I guess it's what you were trying to achive.